# cppcheck --suppress command line parameter doesn't work

Tags: c++, static-analysis, cppcheck

want to suppress all error checks in some file. My command line command is

```
cppcheck --enable=all -j 4 --output-file=out.txt --project=solution.sln --suppress=*:file.cpp
```

But I got errors from file.cpp in my output file. I used to have quite similar(as far as I recall) command line before and it suppress all checks in the file, but ,u some reason now it doesn't work now. Is my command line wrong?

I know  can use suppression file, but I prefer command line parameter and also want to figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: need to supply a relative path for file.cpp? If the errors in your output file have a relative path to file.cpp, use that same path in the `--suppress` argument.

Answer (score 1):

The suppression needs to match the file path as shown in the result.

If you specify a relative folder/file to check that is straight forward and you can just use the structure from your current folder.
But if you are checking with `--project` or an absolute path you need to specify `-rp` (as in "root path") to tell Cppcheck where to base the file paths from. In your case just adding `-rp=.` should fix the issue - at least it will change the paths in the result from absolute ones to relative ones which are the ones you have to use in your suppression.